# Java Error: NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm totally new in this world. I want to make a simple file move program. It works fine with only 1 file and until I add the new code for multiple files move. But I wanted more and I added multiple file selection to `JFileChooser`. To do the move of files I search around the web and found some users that asked for something similar to it. I tried to put it in my code but I've obtained an Error like this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jfile.main(jfile.java:27)

Line 27 is:  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

This is the code, thanks you and sorry for my bad English.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class jfile {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Creado por: MarcosCT7");

    if (new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods").exists());{
        System.out.println("Seleccione el mod a instalar:");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Se está instalando " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    File fuente = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    File destino = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods");

                    File[] files = fuente.listFiles(); //thats new added
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        File destFile = new File(destino.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+files[i].getName().replace(",", "")
                                .replace("[", "") 
                                .replace("]", "")
                                .replace(" ", "")); //until here its new added
                        FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(files[i], destFile, true); //changed to multiple move, before it was: FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(fuente, destino, true);
                    }

                }

         else {
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("No se ha seleccionado ningun mod. Adios.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 27?

Comment: Line 27 is: for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

Comment: I've flaged it because I cannot delete the question, apologizes @l4mpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NullPointerException` means that the variable doesn't hold any reference to a object. What I mean by reference is, For ex:

```
String path="";
File f=new File(path);
if(f.exists()) {
   // do something
}
```

f is a variable of type File which holds a reference to a object File defined by `path`
and now you can use variable f just like any other variable call methods on that variable etc.
Another example

```
File f;

if(f.exists()) {
   // do something
}
```

Now you will get NullPointerException in line `if(f.exists())` because f doesn't hold any reference.

In JAVA `new` keyword is used to assign new reference. JVM will take care of all the low level details. It is similar to pointers in c and c++. In JAVA you don't have to explicitly delete the objects. JVM garbage collector will take care of these things. Java is object oriented language

Do read and understand OOP comcepts

Answer (score 0):

Before you iterate through files using the loop, check using an if statement:

```
if(files==null){
    System.out.println("Files not found");
}
else{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    File destFile = new File(destino.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+files[i].getName().replace(",", "")
                            .replace("[", "") 
                            .replace("]", "")
                            .replace(" ", "")); //until here its new added
                    FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(files[i], destFile, true); //changed to multiple move, before it was: FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(fuente, destino, true);
                }
}
```

Comment: While that's correct, please don't answer duplicate questions - this one is going to be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it soon, and could then be automatically deleted after 9 days if it doesn't have any upvoted or accepted answers. If now someone upvotes your answer or OP accepts it, this would mean the question can't be deleted by the system anymore and would stay around indefinitely until it's deleted manually by either five high-rep users or a mod.

Comment: I'm sorry for duplicate a thread, but I can't understand well the link you show me, I know I'm totally a beginner and maybe I must do easier things to my level. Although this answer helped me a lot to understand what's happening in my error. Sorry I will delete this post, It wasn't my intention to be annoying others.

Comment: Well, then hopefully @MarcosCT7 or someone else who finds this solution useful should upvote it. :)